# Inserting node in a binary search tree using temporary variable

Tags: binary-search-tree

```
enter code here please help me to solve 
    import sys
```

class Node:
def **init**(self,d):
self.left=None
self.data=d
self.right=None
global r
r=None
def insert():
global r
d=int(input('enter data:'))
if(r is None):
r=Node(d)
else:
t=r
while(t!=None):
if(d>t.data):
t=t.right
else:
t=t.left
t=Node(d)
print(r.left)
print(t.data)

```
while(True):
    print('1.insert')
    print('2.delete')
    print('3.display')
    print('4.exit')
    ch=int(input('enter choice:'))
    
    if(ch==1):
        insert()
    if(ch==2):
        delete()
    if(ch==3):
        display()
    if(ch==4):
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
   this my code

import sys
class Node:
    def __init__(self,d):
        self.left=None
        self.data=d
        self.right=None
global r
r=None
def insert():
    global r
    d=int(input('enter data:'))
    if(r is None):
        r=Node(d)
    else:
        t=r
        while(t!=None):
            if(d>t.data):
                t=t.right
            else:
                t=t.left
        t=Node(d)
        print(r.left)
        print(t.data)
                
while(True):
    print('1.insert')
    print('2.delete')
    print('3.display')
    print('4.exit')
    ch=int(input('enter choice:'))
    
    if(ch==1):
        insert()
    if(ch==2):
        delete()
    if(ch==3):
        display()
    if(ch==4):
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).